# No endomorphisms a,b such that ab-ba=identity

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let V be a non-zero finite dimensional real vector space. Show that there are no endomorphisms a,b such that ab-ba=identity.

I proved that b must be surjective but i'm getting stuck right after and i can't seem to find any way.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$n = tr(I) = tr(AB-BA) = tr(AB)-tr(BA) = tr(AB)-tr(AB) = 0$